# получить значение из self, не создавая отдельный метод в rust impl

Tags: ооп, rust

```
pub struct Test {
    value: i128,
}

impl Test {
    pub fn set_value(v: i128) -> Test {
        Test { value: v }
    }

    pub fn show(&self) -> i128 {
        self.value
    }
}
```

```
let t = Test.set_value(11);
t.show(); <- Получить значение "value"
```

Возможно ли обращаться к `self` напрямую через экземпляр структуры, по аналогии с классами python?

```
let t = Test::set_value(11);
t.value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Объявить общедоступное поле `{ pub field_name: T }`.

В вопросе, видимо, опечатка `Test.set_value(11)` <- тут еще нет никакого `self`, надо так `Test::set_value(11)`.

```rust
mod foobar {
    pub struct Test {
        pub value: i128,
     // ^^^
    }

    impl Test {
        // Имя функции не очень подходит к созданию
        // pub fn set_value(v: i128) -> Test
        // ... скорее его надо назвать так
        pub fn from(v: i128) -> Test {
            Test { value: v }
        }
    }
}

use foobar::*;

fn main() {
    let t = Test::from(1);
    // Доступ к полю
    let v = t.value;
    println!("value: {}", v);

    // ... а если изменять то так
    let mut tm = Test::from(1);
    tm.value += 2;
    println!("value: {}", tm.value);
}
```

[PlayGround](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3b60c834d7404a2a20b66bb2800d4f1a)

Comment: Спасибо огромное!